# Can't print integer and string from class without parentheses and quotation marks

Tags: python, string, class, object, printing

I'm trying to create a counter that'll show time elapsed from the time the program is launched. I'm new to OOP so I decided to learn with this. I'm having problem printing the output without parentheses and quotation marks

Here's the  code:

```
from platform import system as system_name
from os import system as system_call
from time import sleep
class Countr(object):
  def __init__(self,second,minute,hour,day,week,month,year,decade,century,):
    self.second = second
    self.minute = minute
    self.hour =  hour
    self.day = day
    self.week = week
    self.month = month
    self.year = year
    self.decade = decade
    self.century = century
    self.ce="0 centuries"
    self.de="0 decades"
    self.y="0 yrs"
    self.mo="0 mths"
    self.w="0 wks"
    self.d="0 days"
    self.h="0 hrs"
    self.m="0 mins"



 def outpt(self):
    if (self.second==1):
        self.s=(self.second , "sec")
    else:
        self.s=(self.second , "secs")
    if (self.second==60):
        self.minute +=1
        self.second = 0
        if (self.minute==1):
            self.m=(self.minute , "min ")
        else:
            self.m=(self.minute , "mins ")
    elif (self.minute==60):
        self.hour +=1
        self.minute = 0
        if (self.hour==1):
            self.h=(self.hour , "hr ")
        else:
            self.h=(self.hour , "hrs ")
    elif (self.hour==24):
        self.day +=1
        self.minute = 0
        if (self.day==1):
            self.d=(self.day , "day ")
        else:
            self.d=(self.day , "days ")
    elif (self.day==7):
        self.week +=1
        self.day = 0
        if (self.week==1):
            self.w=(self.week , "wk ")
        else:
            self.w=(self.week , "wks ")
    elif (self.week==4):
        self.month +=1
        self.week = 0
        if (self.month==1):
            self.mo=(self.month , "mth ")
        else:
            self.m=(self.month , "mths ")
    elif (self.month==12):
        self.year +=1
        self.month = 0
        if (self.year==1):
            self.y=(self.year , "yr ")
        else:
            self.y=(self.year , "yrs ")
    elif (self.year==10):
        self.decade +=1
        self.year = 0
        if (self.decade==1):
            self.de=(self.decade , "decade ")
        else:
            self.de=(self.decade , "decades ")
    elif (self.decade==10):
        self.century +=1
        self.decade = 0
        if (self.century==1):
            self.ce=(self.century , "century ")
        else:
            self.ce=(self.century , "centuries ")
    print ((self.ce),(self.de),(self.y),(self.mo),(self.w),(self.d),(self.h),(self.m),(self.s))

initial= Countr(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
while 1:
    sleep(1)
    command = "cls"
    system_call(command)
    initial.second += 1
    initial.outpt()
```

Everything works fine except it prints like this:

```
0 centuries 0 decades 0 yrs 0 mths 0wks 0 days 0 hrs (14, 'mins ') (6, 'secs')
```

Please... I need your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've got mixed formats for your attributes. they're initialised as strings, then dependent on various conditions, might be reassigned to (int, string) tuple. Perhaps you mean e.g.

```
self.h = str(self.hour) + "hr "
```

I suspect the confusion has come from how print turns what looks like tuples into concatenated strings ...

```
>>> print(1, "cat")
1 cat
```

But it's just a variable number of arguments it's printing, concatenated with spaces, on one line - no tuple there. Conversely, printing a tuple gives ...

```
>>> a = (1, "cat")
>>> print(a)
(1, 'cat')
```

where you'd want instead

```
>>> a = str(1) + " cat"
>>> print(a)
1 cat
```

That is, you can't copy the print function-call syntax to create strings by using comma-separated values

note: when you `print(...)`, all the inner parentheses are redundant as they only enclose one object